# 'match.params.id' is missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

For this project, I am following a tutorial. I am a beginner.

My code is throwing an error at

```
console.log(props.match.params.id);
```

This is the error

```
'match.params.id' is missing in props validation
```

If I change it to console.log(props), it prints {}, which is empty?

What I want it to do is print the id of the product page, in this case it would be 2. "http://localhost:3000/product/2" How can I get this to work?

Here is my full ProductScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';

function ProductScreen(props) {
    console.log(props.match.params.id);
    return <div>ProductScreen</div>
}
export default ProductScreen;
```

And here is app.js with my HTML in it

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import ProductScreen from './Screens/ProductScreen';

function App() {

  const openMenu = () =>{
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.add("open");
  }
  const closeMenu = () =>{
    document.querySelector(".sidebar").classList.remove("open");
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="grid-container">
            <header className="header">
                <div className="brand">
                    <button onClick={openMenu}>
                        &#9776;
                    </button>
                    <Link to="/" >E-Commerce</Link>
                </div>
                <div className="header-links">
                    <a href="signin">Sign In</a>
                    <a href="cart.html">Cart</a>
                </div>
            </header>
            <aside className="sidebar">
                <h3>Shopping Categories</h3>
                <button className="sidebar-close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>x</button>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Pants</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Shirts</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
            <main className="main">
                <div className="content">
                  <Routes>
                  <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
                  <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen/>} />
                  </Routes>
                    
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer className="footer">
                All rights reserved.
            </footer>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm sorry if that's too much or too little information, this is my first post here.

Comment: Your `ProductScreen` doesn't seem to have _any_ props validation, presumably that error is coming from https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md which also shows how to write valid code. But also you should probably be using the _hooks_ for accessing route information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing any props to the `ProductScreen` component, do this instead

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ProductScreen(props) {
    // console.log(props.match.params.id);
    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);
    return <div>ProductScreen</div>
}
export default ProductScreen;
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you. It works perfectly when I take out 'props' entirely, including from function ProductScreen(). Thank you

Comment: @Sara glad I could help, can you mark it as an answer then? This will be helpful to folks who might run into a similar issue.